# Spring Boot hot deployment in production

Tags: spring

I have multiple spring boot based micro services. Can we enable hot deployment of those micro services in production environment. If yes how we can do it. Please note : currently we don't have docker. And though the services artifacts are jar, we can turn those to war.

Answer (score 0):

Hot deployment is not a feature of Spring Boot so it's not correct to consider it configurable (enabled or disabled).
Hot deployment is a feature of application servers (tomcat, jboss, jetty, etc) where you deploy your WARs. If they supports hot deployment (most of them do!) then it's OK to replace WARs on-the-fly so they will be re-deployed.